# how to calculate prevalence using sql code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to calculate prevalence in sql.
kind of stuck in writing the code.
I want to make automative code.

I have check that I have 1453477 of sample size and number of people who has disease is 851451 using count. 
The formula of calculating prevalence is no.of person who has disease/no.sample size.

```
select (COUNT(condition_id)/COUNT(person_id)) as prevalence
from disease
where condition_id=12345;
```

when I run above code, I get 1 as a output where I am suppose to get 0.5858.

Can some one please help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: may depend on which DBMS you're using ... Perhaps you get round by division operator.

Comment: I am using postgre

Comment: You want decimal arithmetic. Currently `count(..)/Count()` is an integer expression.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I CAST AS DECIMAL in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487440/how-do-i-cast-as-decimal-in-postgresql)

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast by

`count(...)/count(...)::numeric(6,4)` or

`count(...)/count(...)::decimal`

as two options.

Important point is apply cast to `denominator` or `numerator` part(in this case `denominator`), Do not apply to division as

`(count(...)/count(...))::numeric(6,4)` which again results an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your current query you count the number of rows in the disease table, once using the column condition_id, once using the column person_id. But the number of rows is the same - this is why you get 1 as a result.

I think you need to find the number of different values for these columns. This can be done using count distinct:

```sql
select (COUNT(DISTINCT condition_id)/COUNT(DISTINCT person_id)) as prevalence
from disease
where condition_id=12345;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the logic that you want is something like this:

```
select avg( (condition_id = 12345)::int )
from disease;
```

Your version doesn't have the sample size, because you are filtering out people without the condition.

If you have duplicate people in the data, then this is a little more complicated.  One method is:

```
select (count(distinct person_id) filter (where condition_id = 12345)::numeric /
        count(distinct person_id
       )
from disease;
```